# JavaScript compression error while compressing JSDOM with JSMin

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, hammer.js, jsdom, jsmin

My project is developed with TypeScript for frontend.

- Mocha - for unit test
- JSDOM - for DOM mocking
- Hammer.js - for touch UX
- Grunt, JSMin, etc.

The project file structure is something like this:

```
index.ts
mymodule.ts
mymodule_test.ts
```

As Hammer.js uses the global `window` and `document` object internally, I added some tricky code before the import statement for test only purposes.

`mymodule.ts`

```js
1: import * as jsdom from 'jsdom';
2: if (typeof window === 'undefined') {
3:     let testDom: HTMLDocument = jsdom.jsdom('', undefined);
4:     (<any> global).window = testDom.defaultView;
5:     (<any> global).document = testDom;
6: }
7: import * as Hammer from 'hammerjs';
...
```

Now test runs successfuly. But build fails and spits out the following error:

```
Running "shell:minify" (shell) task

/home/yunbo/Workspace/jobkey/frontend/node_modules/jsmin/jsmin.js:231
            throw 'Error: unterminated string literal: ' + a;
            ^
Error: unterminated string literal:
```

I searched for a while and found some Q&As about such an error.
To avoid that error, I should modify the JSDOM's internal code or remove 1 - 6 lines in `mymodule.ts`. But both are not affordable.

- If I remove 1 - 6 lines in `mymodule.ts`, I cannot run the tests.
- modifying the original code of JSDOM or JSMin seems not the right way.

How can I solve this issue? Should I use another JavaScript minifier? Or should not test `mymodule.js` that includes Hammer.js import statement?

Comment: I temporarily solved this problem using __Terser__. As a friend of mine proposed, I tried UglifyJS 3, JSMin 2, and Terser. Only Terser was able to compress JSDOM.

Comment: But a more detailed explanation or another approach will be accepted as a valid answer. Please let me know more about this issue. Thank you.